# Can you copy the weights from just the first 3 layers of a network? Not exactly finetuning, but almost reshaping

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

In caffe I was looking to only use the pretrained weights for the alexnet architecture trained using the ImageNet dataset, for just the first two layers, and I would like to add a softmax classifier after those two layers. I was wondering how I could go about extracting only those first two layer's weights from a weight file that contains a much larger network structure (the true "deep" Alexnet structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to [Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46421904/1714410)'s answer -
In case you don't want the full weights file,
In order to extract the weights of the desired layers, use [net surgery](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb):

```
net = caffe.Net(prototxt, caffemodel, caffe.TRAIN)
outnet = caffe.Net(predefined_prototxt_with_desired_layers_only, caffe.TRAIN)
layers_to_copy = ['conv1', 'conv2', 'conv3']
for layer in layers_to_copy:
    for i in range(0, len(net.params[layer])): #this is for copying both weights and bias, in case bias exists
        outnet.params[layer][i].data[...]=np.copy(net.params[layer][i].data[...])

outnet.save(new_caffemodel_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Caffe uses the layer's `"name"` to assign weights to layer's `blobs`. 
If you change the top layers' `"name"`s than caffe will not copy the weights from the original `.caffemodel` file.